# Decompress header of swf file (possible with qUncompress?)

Tags: qt, flash

I have some swf files generated with Adobe Flash.
Does anybody know how can I decompress their headers in QT?
I need their size (width and height) , frame rate and frame count.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not documented if `qUncompress` requires that all compressed data to be in the `QByteArray` to decompress it. From the [wording](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qbytearray.html#qUncompress) of it, it seems to imply that. I would imagine loading some large SWF into memory just to get a few bytes in the header is not practical.

If you can live with loading the whole file into memory, just load the file starting at offset 4 into a `QByteArray` and flip the byte order of the 1st 4 (SWF is little-endian and `qUncompress` requires the length to be in [big-endian](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qbytearray.html#qUncompress)). Subtract 4 from the flipped 32-bit integer. Then call `qUncompress`.

If loading the whole file is not ideal, you may be better off use the stream functions in `zlib` directly. That allows you to decompress data piece by piece.

Comment: Also the length of the file is compressed.

Comment: According the spec at http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf_file_format_spec_v10.pdf (page 25), the first 8 bytes are not compressed. File length (decompressed) is part of the first 8 bytes.